# Writing a string which contains " "

Tags: c#

I have a string from an xml document:

```
<title type="html">
```

Is there a way for me to write this string like `"<title type="html">"`? I've had similar problems writing javascript as a string but I did see some solutions in the past (which I can't remember)?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can escape quotes in a string using a \

```
String s = "this is my \"data\" in the string";
```

Answer (score 28):

You need to escape your double quotes..

```
string blah = "<title type=\"html\">";

OR

string blah = @"<title type=""html"">";
```

Alternatively you could use single quotes in your tag, which will serve the same purpose.

```
string blah = "<title type='html'>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape:

```
var str = "<font color=\"red\">;";
```

(Edit: forgot to put proper html chars in!)

Or in javascript you can use single quotes to contain one with doubles:

```
var str = '<font color="red">';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it like this:

```
string f = @"<font color=""red"">";
```

Check out [msdn on string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a large string with a lot of XML, one approach would be to write

```
var str = @"<tag attribute=`value`><SubTag OtherAttribute=`OtherValue` /></tag>".Replace('`', '"');
```

Beware that this will be less efficient at runtime, because of the call to Replace().

The best way to handle this is might be to put the markup in a separate text file and embed it in a ResX file.  That would allow you to write `Properties.Resources.Markup`.

Answer (score 1):

string jason = "This string contains a \"";