# How to write quoted strings to files in C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am making a new .csv file in C# using StreamWriter and writing to this file with the `WriteLine("stuff to write")` method. My problem is I cannot seem to write quoted strings, i.e. `WriteLine(" "dog" ")` where "dog" is itself quoted. I tried using the double quote method: `WriteLine(@"""dog""")` but it still didn't work (just wrote `dog` in the csv file). How can I write quoted strings to files?

Comment: Have you tried `WriteLine("\"dog\"")`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: Are you going to write multiple line text to the file?

Comment: First hit on a google search of "How to write quoted strings to files in C#?" is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974877/writing-a-string-which-contains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're opening this in Excel, which is why you're not seeing the quotes - Excel tries to be smart when you open CSV files, so it's taking out your quotes, even though they are there in the raw file.

Open your result file in a text editor, and you'll see the quotes when you do your `WriteLine(@"""dog""")` approach (or the more common `WriteLine("\"dog\"")`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `\"`in your stings when you want to have a quote sign.

```
WriteLine("something with the \"quote\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the double quotation mark is considered as a special character you have to [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) them if you want to use its literal representation.

```
WriteLine("\"dog\"")
```